# How to send facebook user information into another view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, sqlite

I'm trying to save the username and user email after a user logs into my app through facebook.
I have set up a segue to pass the info from the login view controller to the view controller where I plan to save the user strings and some other strings into my sqlite database.
When I do run my app in the destination view controller and try to insert all the data into sqlite, I am thrown an error saying the userName and the userEmail are nil strings, so my data is not being saved. I have correctly set up the segue; synthesized, added properties. But it seems to me the problem may be how I'm retrieving the data. Help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"loginInfo"]) {
        NSString *name = user.name;
        NSString *email = [user objectForKey:@"email"];
        ViewController *vc = (ViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        vc.userName = name;
        vc.userEmail = email;
        NSLog(@"user data is being prepared to segue");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the 'user' is the user from facebook, whoever is logged in facebook on my app. I think the segue works fine, but for some reason the string is being returned as nil, so im guessing im not saving the string correctly before its being segued.

Answer (score 0):

You used -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue user:(id)user sender:(id)sender

There is no such method for segue unwinding in UIViewController class. Instead of that Use -

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"loginInfo"]) {
        NSString *name = user.name;
        NSString *email = [user objectForKey:@"email"];
        ViewController *vc = (ViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        vc.userName = name;
        vc.userEmail = email;
        NSLog(@"user data %@, email %@",name,email);
     }
}
```

To get the user info you need to implement facebook delegate.

```
- (void)meRequestResult:(id)result WithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"result %@",result );

    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        NSDictionary *dictionary;
        if([result objectForKey:@"data"])
            dictionary = (NSDictionary *)[(NSArray *)[result objectForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:0];
        else
            dictionary = (NSDictionary *)result;


        email = [dictionary valueForKey:@"email"];
        fName = [dictionary valueForKey:@"first_name"];
        lName = [dictionary valueForKey:@"last_name"];

     }
}
```

Comment: if I remove user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user, user.name becomes an undeclared identifier, so how to i return the data from the facebook login so that I can save it?

Comment: declare instance variable FBGraphUser *fbUser in your .h file. And in the facebook delegate save FBGraphUser data object in fbUser. Then you will be able to access fbUser object in any method of your .m file. accept the answer if it helps.

Comment: so the FBGraphUser isn't a class, its a protocol, i've already added it to my class, so then what should i be declaring?

Comment: Then you need to find a way to access fb user's name & emailID. You must go to https://developers.facebook.com/

Comment: i've been reading over the documents and im still confused. i've logged in and requested permissons. my console shows that the email and username have been retrieved but i am unable to store it

Comment: In my project i've used facebook delegate method to access user info, which i have edited in the answer given above.